# Is Boot Camp still being supported by Apple?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, trackpad

Boot Camp seems to have become the orphan child of Apple recently - more and more things seem to not be working as of the current Windows 10 (1903) release. These are at least the problems I am now seeing (running macOS 10.14.6 on a Late 2013 15" MBP):

- Boot Camp control panel does not start on startup
- Trackpad configuration settings are not saved (e.g. tap to click, 2
  finger-click for right-click, etc)
- No option in Boot Camp control panel to select starting from macOS boot volume (apparently no APFS support) (requires holding down Option at startup to select macOS boot volume)

When I download the latest **Windows Support Software** from `Boot Camp Assistant.app`, the most recent "last modified" dates in the files are March 2016.

Has Apple announced either way, whether they plan to continue to update Windows Support Software or not?

Comment: Yah I *have* noticed that driver updates for Windows Boot Camp have been thin on the ground. In some cases you can suss out the hardware in question via-device manager (booted into Windows, of course) and find a workable substitute on the manufacturers website, but I'm not sure about your specific issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support site is alive and kicking but since the product is Intel only, we can presume it might be at the end of the line for future Apple Silicon Macs until such time a new announcement is made by Apple.

- https://support.apple.com/boot-camp
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468

There were no announcements of note relating to this from WWDC 2019 through September 2021. That could change tomorrow, of course.

I’ve moved almost all my work devices over to VMware Fusion FWIW. There are plenty of reasons to not virtualize, so I encourage everyone still in the boot camp - check out Boot Runner - it’s amazing value and super helpful for managing one or more installations. If you have more advanced needs, Winclone Pro (or Winclone) are also available.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner/
- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone-pro/

We haven’t spent any time with Windows on ARM but that would change if we had a need to explore it.